# Problem using VS Code's Code Runner to run js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, vscode-code-runner

I've installed the vs code extension Code Runner to help me learn JS, but it doesn't seem to be working. When I try to run this simple console log, I get no output in vs code terminal, just this message: "[Running] node "c:\Users\vaio\Desktop\react\script.js" and nothing else, not even the massage saying that the execution ended.

At the same time, if i use windows cmd and use "node script.js" it works perfectly fine.

The code for the script.js is just:

```
console.log("Hello, World")
```

Can someone help me? (let me know if i have to share any other files)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need Code Runner to run JavaScript in VS Code as VS Code is written in JavaScript and has a built-in JavaScript interpreter. Remove the extension, load your JavaScript file, and then click the play arrow button in the top-right of the window, or type CTRL+ALT+N.